# Do we need hyperledger fabric on our system before setting up hyperledger composer locally?

Tags: ubuntu, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am setting up hyperledger composer on my local linux machine. I haven't seen hyperledger fabric in prerequisite list for composer installation guide. Do I need to setup fabric first or composer can work on its own without fabric?

Answer (score 1):

the pre-requisites section defines what's require to INSTALL Composer modules. Fabric is provided as a dockerized, development environment to get going.

if you read any of our Composer docs, you'll see it mentions Fabric as the runtime blockchain presently. It runs in docker.

In our Dev Tools guide - we mention Hyperledger Fabric and how you can get it spun up (so that you can use Composer to deploy business networks to it)

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/installing/development-tools.html

Scroll down and it says "Step 2: Starting Hyperledger Fabric"

In our tutorials - such as the Developer tutorial -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html

we show how to deploy a sample tutorial network to a one peer, one CA development Fabric runtime and  blockchain network (so that you can get going with Composer)